# Strange SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc

I get the following error not per each DB query, but randomly with ~1% probability per any query. No matters what query is, it may execute successfully, and then fails on the same query.

Error occurs only when I run my app as tomcat web app. Unit tests or standalone application mode (`SpringApplication.run()`) don't fail.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost
:5432/db_name
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:980)
        at package.MyDBService.insert(MyDBService.java:32)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name?tcpKeepAlive=true
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        ... 15 more
```

## How I connect to DB

I use tomcat8 and Spring.

```
@Configuration
public class JdbcFactory {
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return new JdbcTemplate(new DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_name?tcpKeepAlive=true", "user", "pass"));
    }
}
```

This is how my typical DAO looks like

```
@Service
public class CommonDAO {
    @Autowired JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public String getSome() {
        return jdbc.query("...");
    }
}
```

JDBC-driver is provided as a maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

There are no more another DB-connection configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say what exactly is happening here. You could have something flaky about the network between your application and the database. Also Tomcat isn't meant to use a JDBC driver out of WEB-INF/lib, the driver registration process will cause classloader problems.

Using a connection pool would help a lot. You'll drastically reduce the amount of connection-creating, you can configure it to test the connections before you use them, so if you do get a bad connection it will be discarded and replaced. It will also be a lot faster since it will reuse existing connections.

[Configure a dataSource in Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), and put the JDBC driver jar in the Tomcat shared lib.